# How can I get the best out of the Google Apps Script debugger?

Tags: google-apps-script

It seems to me that the debugger in GAS is really poor. Firstly, the information shown about a variable is really basic, and does not really aid with the debugging process at all.

For example, if I have an array of `GmailThread`, I cannot see any information about the threads. The only way I can find a particular property of the thread is to do a console log.

[image]

Even with the "show all data" option selected (which makes the debugger even slower than before), I can't actually see any useful data.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Are there any extensions/third-party IDEs which can be used for better debugging?

Comment: You might like to use command line interface using Clasp in the Guide section of the documentation. But in general I find the debugger to be very useful and lightweight. Coupled with the Logger and the console and the stack debugger it’s quite a useful set of tools. But this not the type of question for this forum as it tends to generate a lot of opinionated answers.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your objects on Apps Script, use the [`Logger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) class or read the [*Execution Transcripts*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript) on the Google platform.

Hope this helps!